# How to Add multiple links Material Textfield

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

How do I convert the text in MaterialUI TextField as Hyperlink TextField will be disabled when rendered, I have to display multiple links separated by comma some times.

```
{!this.state.disableEdit ? (
                  <TextField
                    multiline
                    rowsMax={15}
                    name="majorIncidentNumber"
                    variant="outlined"
                    label="MI Number"
                    defaultValue={impact.mi_number}
                    InputProps={{
                      readOnly: true,
                    }}
                  />
                ) : (
                  <TextField
                    multiline
                    rowsMax={15}
                    variant="outlined"
                    name="majorIncidentNumber"
                    label="MI Number"
                    defaultValue={this.state.majorIncidentNumber}
                    onChange={this.handleTextChange.bind(this)}
                    helperText="e.g. "MI0009164","MI00092345"
                  />
                )}
```

In the above code I want to display the `{impact.mi_number}` as hyperlinks, it is comma separated **string**. I can wrap entire thing `<a></a>` but it won't work when I have multiple links,

Answer (score 0):

So `impact.mi_number` is like `"link1,link2,link3"`

I would use `<Link>` from Material-UI (or you can use TextField up to you)

```
import Link from '@material-ui/core/Link';

{impact.mi_number.split(",").map(link => (
  <Link>{link}</Link>
))}
```

Comment: I have to render those links inside TexField, <Link></Link> tag can't be used inside the TextField tag, It renders <Link></Link> tag as ```[Object Object]```

Comment: why not use many TextFields?

`{impact.mi_number.split(",").map(link => (<TextField>{link}</TextField>))}`